# Maintaining MAMP for PHP development and separate MySQL install for Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, mamp

I'm new to RoR. I have a separate install of MySQL that I've been using the command line to access. I also have MAMP PRO on my machine for PHP development. I am having trouble finding out how to switch back to MAMP PRO installation when I'm
working with PHP. I am assuming the issue is related to them using the same sockets although as a newbie to this particular situation I am unsure. My research has failed to yield the answer to this exact situation. Most questions have related to using MAMP with RoR. Some advice on whether having 2 installs of MySQL on the same Mac is possible/a reasonable thing to do would be appreciated.

Comment: you can do this https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/3429066

Answer (score 0):

I tried MAMP but needed SNMP support so I moved to XAMPP. I also had two MySQL installs running at various times and it was always a problem to keep everything in sync. Then I realized that I should probably just be running everything natively on the Mac, which comes with Apache, PHP, and Ruby anyway. This site helped me get that all going - http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/. Everything - PHP/CakePHP and Ruby On Rails - works perfectly now.

Answer (score -1):

It greatly depends on how you have MAMP setup, but does specifying the port at the end of your PHP environment help?  (MAMP uses 8888 by default I believe)

```
http://yourdomain:8888
```